# Please explain parameter of startActivityForResult

Tags: android

Please explain about PICK_CONTACT. Why it equals 1 and what does it mean?

```
public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;



Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);  //should filter only contacts with phone numbers       
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an arbitrary integer >= 0 you can choose yourself. It is called `requestCode`.

It's useful in case you need to identify in `onActivityResult()` the `startActivityForResult()` request you made.

(Also, as a special case, if you call `startActivityForResult()` with request code >= 0 in an activity `onCreate()`, that activity's window doesn't get displayed.)